# ¿Porqué Visual Studio a veces deja de guardar los cambios?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy usando **Visual Studio 2015**, y me ha pasado varias veces que cuando estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto y hago nuevos cambios, al compilar esos cambios no surten efecto en el resultado final de mi aplicación, a pesar de que se ven reflejados en mis ficheros .cs.

Por ejemplo tengo una aplicación similar a una Calculadora, ya tiene implementado todas las funcionalidades de los botones menos el de AC o el C, cuando se los implemento y compilo sale como si nunca hubiera hecho esa operación.

Me he dado cuenta que normalmente me sucede en proyectos un poco grandes (Más de 24 Clases, Más de 10 Formularios, Más de 6 Ensamblados externos, etc), no se si esto influya; pero me gustaría saber cómo solucionarlo, porque a veces he tenido que comenzar de nuevo e ir copiando los datos del proyecto viejo.

Gracias

Comment: Has intentado hacer Clear/Limpiar la solucion? Muchas veces el cache hace que no se reflejen ciertos cambios.

Comment: Lo voy hacer apenas me vuelva a dar ese problema. Gracias. Si soluciono el error te avisare para que el comentario lo pongas como respuesta y marcarla como la indicada.

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción es cuando compiles hacerlo con CTRL+F5, en mi caso una vez me pasó en modo **debug** y tuve que ir a **Administrador de depuración** y marcar **Compilación** para que siempre que ejecutara el proyecto compilara la solución.

[image: **Administrador de depuración**]

Marcar Compilación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva la respuesta y funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Cada que realizas una compilación, se verifican dependencias de proyectos, de paquetes de nugets, se copian archivos, se generan de nuevo las DLLs, etc. Justo como mencionas, dependiendo del tamaño de la solución y de los proyectos, el VS puede "enviciarse" y dejar de refrescar las DLLs, por lo que a veces no verás tus cambios reflejados cuando estás debugeando tu aplicación.

Para evitar eso es necesario que con frecuencia ejecutes la opción "Clean Solution" y luego "Build Solution", o en su defecto la opción "Rebuild Solution" la cual realiza ambos pasos.

Comment: Que sucede si creo un proyecto en VStudio Profesional 2015, lo edito en el 2017 bajo el mismo NET Framework 4.5.2 y posteriormente abro el mismo en el 2015? Pregunto esto pq una de las veces que me sucede este error es en estas circunstancias.

Comment: Hola @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas. Eso no es algo que esté relacionado con que las DLLs no se vuelvan compilar. El problema en sí es algo común en todos los IDEs. Abrir una solución de VS 2017 en VS 2015, tampoco debería representar un problema... siempre y cuando, VS 2015 tenga soporte para los proyectos y funcionalidades que maneja VS 2017.

Comment: No hago nada nuevo que con el 2015 no se pueda hacer inclusive mantengo el mismo C# para evitar conflictos.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente borras de tu proyecto la carpeta "obj" lo se resuelves. Al compilar se vuelve a crear sin problemas.

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Esto no proporciona una solución a la pregunta, en cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), pues [es mejor dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/586/por-qu%c3%a9-necesito-50-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n-para-comentar-qu%c3%a9-alternativa-tengo)